# How to send an ItemControl Item's location for nested collections

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatemplate, itemscontrol

I have an ItemControl that is bound to an `ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<BookModel>>`. Each item at the deeppest ItemControl has a button. I implemented a command that fires every time the button is clicked.
My problem is that I don't know which parameter should I pass to the execution method in order to know which Item fired the command. Meaning, if the button functions as an "Add Book" button, I want to know where should I insert a BookModel object

```
<UserControl.Resources>
<DataTemplate x:Key="BooksViewTemplate">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock>
            <!-- This is where I bind data to the BookModel -->
        </TextBlock>
        <Button x:Name="AddNewBook"
                Command="{Binding ElementName=LayoutRoot, Path = DataContext.AddBookCommand}"
                <!-- CommandParameter=  -->
        />
    </StackPanel>
</<DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate_level1">
    <StackPanel>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource BooksViewTemplate}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Books}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplate_level1}" DataContext="{Binding}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

```
public ICommand AddBookCommand
{
    get
    {
        return _addBookCommnad ?? (_addBookCommand = new CmandHandler<object>((par) => AddBookAction(par), _canExecute));
    }
}

public void AddBookAction(object obj)
{
    //This is where I want to add a new BookModel to the 
    IObservableCollection<IObservableCollection<BookModel>> at the location 
    given by the pressed button
}
```

Comment: Are you just trying to find the spot to insert the new book? Or is this a hierarchy where you need to know the parent that you are adding the book to?

Comment: Can you pass just "this"? CommandParameter="{Binding . }" ?

Comment: @KevinCook Not sure I understood your question. I want to know both to which column to add the new book and to which row to insert it, which should have affect on the `Iobservable<Iobservable<BookModel>`

Comment: Just trying to see why you need to know the row.  Why not just use <collection<BookModel>> and then use a wrappanel if you need to display it in a grid format.  That's why I was asking about a hierarchy.

Comment: @TobiasMoeThorstensen - you can't specify a `Binding` for `CommandParameter` since its no `DependencyProperty`

Comment: @TobiasMoeThorstensen This would pass the item itself and not it's grid location (col. , row) in the ItemControl. I guess I can then search for the item in Books and get it's location, but I was hoping there was a more immediate solution

Comment: @RandRandom Of course you can specify a binding for the command parameter - I've done that for almost a decade

Comment: @TobiasMoeThorstensen - sorry, mixed it up with Binding's `ConverterParameter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an `AlternationIndex` property to get the index. Just set `AlternationCount` in `ItemsControl` to `int.MaxValue`:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding yourcollection}" AlternationCount="2147483647">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

If you pass an item as CommandParameter and search in your collection, then it will work, if you have **no reference duplicates** in the collection, otherwise it fails (you will not know which instance occurrence you should take).

For **nested collection** you can access index such a way:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ColOfCol}" AlternationCount="2147483647">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding }" AlternationCount="2147483647">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock.Text>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource multivalcnv}">
                                    <Binding Path='(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex)' RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentPresenter, AncestorLevel=2}"></Binding>
                                    <Binding Path='(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex)' RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentPresenter, AncestorLevel=1}"></Binding>
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </TextBlock.Text>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

---

```
public class MultValConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values.Length == 2)
        {
            //return (values[0], values[1]); //For the ViewModel
            return (values[0], values[1]).ToString(); //For the UI example
            }
        else
            return Binding.DoNothing;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("It's a one way converter.");
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it gives only the row index in each column, so I still can't figure out which item has fired the command...What I did was setting the `AlternationCount` at the outer DataTemplate's ItemsControl (DataTemplate_level1) and passed the `AlternationIndex` as the command parameter. Is that the right way to implement your solution?

Comment: I have extended my answer with an example for nested collections.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. Your solution works perfectly. I had to change the syntax of the Convert method though to: `return String.Format("{0} {1}", values[0], values[1]);`. Thank you for the quick and elegant solution.